# Detecting individual document property changes in Change Feed

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document type State which is for holding current and historical "state" data. I add a new document to the States collection every time a property in the current state changes, therefore creating "snapshots" of state in the course of time.

I was wondering if I could use the Change Feed and a CosmosDBTrigger to detect changes in individual properties of the State so that I could trigger code based on the change.

Something like this:

```
[FunctionName("StateChangeTrigger")]
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "mydb",
    collectionName: "States",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB",
    LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
    CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, ILogger log)
{
    if (documents != null)
    {
        Document currentDoc = documents[documents.Count-1];
        Document previousDoc;
        if (documents.Count == 1)
        {
            previousDoc = // Fetch previous document from database, based on timestamp
        }
        else
        {
            previousDoc = documents[documents.Count-2];
        }
        if (currentDoc.MyProperty != previousDoc.MyProperty) // Doesn't work but you get my drift
        {
            log.LogInformation("Property 'MyProperty' has been modified");
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

With a CosmosDBTrigger being triggered, obviously we know there is an addition to the collection, but we don't know exactly **which** properties have changed. Is the sample code a valid way of handling this problem? Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `documents` contains a batch of changes, which are ordered for the same Partition Key value. But unless the operations are happening inside a Stored Procedure, you can get one version of the document in one batch, and the next version in the next one, there is nothing assuring you that because they are the same document, they will be in the same batch read, unless they were part of the same transaction (Sproc). Still, this solution won't work if I do 1 edit, because I will have the edit in the change feed, but the previous document won't be the original document.

Comment: Thanks @MatiasQuaranta. I've thought about this more and it's not at all an ideal way to go about it. States belong to devices in my case, and states could be coming from different devices, so keeping track of the changes for each device would be pretty complex.